# C# multiple instances of program reading from same file

Tags: c#, file

I wrote a program that reads from file, processes it according to given parameters and writes some output. I was curious, if there can occur any strange problems when user creates more instances of my program (by opening executable file) and runs them over the same file.

I read from file with while loop and `file.ReadLine()`.

Comment: Does _"writes some output"_ mean that you're writing in the same file that you're reading?

Comment: No, the name of the file is chosen according to parameters from user. I do not want to read and write to the same file. I have one really big file and I would like to let all instances of my program to read from it (but process it different way because of different parameters in each instance) and I am afraid of unexpected behaviour that may occur:))

Answer (score 6):

> I was curious, if there can occur any strange problems when user creates more instances of my program (by opening executable file) and runs them over the same file.

The way this is worded leads me to think that you are concerned that the user might accidently run multiple instances of the program against the same file. If that is your concern, then you can prevent problems from this by opening the file in an exclusive mode. The operating system itself will ensure that only the single instance of the program has access to the file for as long as you hold the file open.

If you access the file with a FileStream object, then I believe that exclusive mode is the default, so you don't have to worry about this at all. Just make sure your stream stays open through all the reads and writes for which consistency is required.

If another instance of the program attempts to open the file, then it will throw a IOException and not allow the access. You can either let the program crash, or you can notify the user that the file is already being used and give them the option to choose another file, or whatever.

**UPDATE**

If you want to read from the same file in many instances of the program, with no instance writing to it, then that is also easily doable. Just open the file in shared read-only mode, and there is no problem at all letting lots of programs read the file simultaneously.

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, 
                                      FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I want them (instances of program) to read that file at the same time:) The calculation takes time (hours), so it would be eficcient to run more instances of program with different parameters over the same file. I am just afraid to do so:)

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem if you are only **reading** from the file.

However, you could use a [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) if you wished that only one program were able to process the file at the same time.

For instance:

```
Boolean isMyFileFree;
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "Mutex4MyFile", out isMyFileFree)) {
    // Process your file
}
```

Comment: Note on Mutext: While using Mutext achieves "only one process able to execute some code" that covers file scenario, it is significanlty more complicated for program itself and does not protect from other processes reading the same file. Simple opening file with correct sharing flags is better for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If they're all reading then there will only be a problem if you lock the file. Using `FileAccess.Read` and `FileShare.Read` will allow them to all open it at the same time.

Comment: They both intend to write to the file, as stated in the question.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment, the OP doesn't say where output will be written

Comment: That's fair enough, and I'm not usually one for assumptions. Otiel has asked for clarification.

Comment: I'm inclined to pedantically avoid assumptions too, though in this case it did read to me like the output was elsewhere. That certainly would cause more complications.

Comment: Yes, every instance wants to read from the same file, but write elsewhere:) Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since both instances potentially write data to the file, you are very much in danger: both in reading and writing there may be corrupt data.

What you ought to do is acquire appropriate permissions / access; for instance, if you're using [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx) to open the file then specify the [`FileAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f.aspx) and [`FileShare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) that is applicable to the current mode of execution.

Now, it is up to you to handle accessibility in the application - have a course to fallback on when one of the instances is "locked out" of the file, so as not to break (which would be just as bad as corrupting the data, no doubt.)

Your handling might well just be to go on hold for a certain timespan with a timeout, and retry, if you want your application to maintain integrity; or you could just drop changes that the conflicting instance would be going to write. This depends on your situation, but you are responsible and do have to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If you using [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx) and passing somthing other than `FileShare.None` to the 4th *share* paramter then it could be possible for other threads or processes to access the file.

If the others only have `Read` access this will be no problem at all, except for when you want to delete the file. If the others have a higher level of access then your code should deal with the alternative possibilities, like the file being altered or deleted.

Note that specifying `FileShare.ReadWrite` extends access to all process that have rights to file, not just those you know of.