# Can I take the ownership of lock when trying to open and write a file through StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I use StreamWriter to write logs. I sometimes open this log file with Excel while my program is running.
I find that Excel lock this file so I get IOException when my program try to write logs.

Can I take out the lock which was set by other process?
I know I can lock the file while my program is running but it cause similar problem when I open it with Excel.
Note that I won't write anything with the other process.

```
        using(var sw = new StreamWriter(
            new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write), Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16")))
```

Comment: Have you tried opening it as read-only in Excel? Otherwise you can't really tell Excel to drop the lock.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't "take ownership of lock on file" (unless other application is designed o allow such access).

The other application must be opening file with particular share mode to allow your to simultaneously access the file.

Note that most application don't open files in such mode due to problems keeping state consistent.

.Net way of specifying share mode - use desired value from [FileShare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration when opening files. There are multiple samples and discussion about it on SO like [C# multiple instances of program reading from same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838784/c-sharp-multiple-instances-of-program-reading-from-same-file).